# Cannot import csv to PostgreSQL using dbWriteTable

Tags: r, postgresql

I tried to use R package RPostgreSQL to direct import csv files into pgAdmin 4. My code is as below:

```
dbWriteTable(localdb$con,'test1',choose.files(), row.names=FALSE)
```

I got the error message:

```
Warning message:
In postgresqlImportFile(conn, name, value, ...) :
  could not load data into table
```

I checked my pgAdmin 4, there does exist a imported table named test1, but it had no observations. Then I imported this csv to R first, and then used dbWriteTable to write it to PostgreSQL, and it worked well. I am not sure which part is wrong.

The reason I am not using psql or pgAdmin 4 to import csv file directly is that I kept getting the error message "relationship does not exist" every time when I use the COPY FROM commands. I am now using R package RPostgreSQL to bypass this issue, but sometimes my data file is too big to import to R. I need to find a way to use the dbWriteTable function to import file directly to PostgreSQL without consuming R's memory.

Comment: I think you should load directly into Postgres if possible, and resolve the errors there.  Using R as as workaround doesn't sound too appetizing to me.

Comment: Well it seems like you are trying to import (in psql or pgadmin) without creating the table. Postgresql cannot guess the table structure.

Comment: @e4c5 I did create a table before I import my data, and it still did not work

Comment: Does not work is a big No-No here. Post your table. Post a few sample rows. Post the exacct error

Comment: Can you import it without using R?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I tried to import through pgAdmin 4 but it did not work and I do not want to create a table in advance, which is not time efficient. I can import data using dbWriteTable in R now, but I found another issue. The issue is that the dbWriteTable seems not able to execute the "header=T" parameter, and always reads data from the first row, I am not sure how to solve this issue.